# Select id's from subquery, containing subquery taking forever, while subquery containing subquery is fast

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

I have a query, with a subquery, and subqueries in that. (i know, its not the most beautifull, but this is becouse of a script what has to get pk's from a excisting query). The first subquery itself, with the others in it, runs fast. Even though its selecting almost 4000 rows. But when i only add a query around it to select only the pk's, it turn into a monster query, its taking up to 15 minutes to perform then. We put neon profiler on it, and it gives us that the productwon/wincode subquery is taking much too long. We allready saw it ourselfs, becouse when leaving that one out, its fast.
So it seems to turn out in a kind of loop hole. Does anyone knows why, or knows a trick to find out why the productwon/wincode subquery is taking so long when inside the outer query?

```
SELECT pk FROM
    (SELECT 
        pk,
        responseset_pk,
        responsedate,
        (SELECT product FROM wincode wincodetable  WHERE wincodetable.product != '' AND  wincodetable.code =  
            (
                (SELECT value_text FROM responses ex3
                    WHERE name = 'Wincode'
                    AND (ex3.responseset_pk = ex.responseset_pk)
                )     
            )
        ) AS productwon,

        (SELECT name FROM branch ex2 WHERE ex2.pk = ex.branch_pk) AS branchename

    FROM responses ex
    WHERE responses.question_pk = 1

) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a co-related subquery. See how the inner subquery refers to the `responseset_pk` of the outer table? That means the entire subquery must be re-run for **every row** returned from the `responses` table.

Co-related subqueries can usually be rewritten as a join that requires only one execution of the subquery, albeit one that returns values for all rows, which is going to be way faster. Your query is no exception.

I think the following should work. I changed the subqueries to joins and replaced the subquery on branch to a simple join to branch.

```
SELECT pk,
    ex.responseset_pk,
    ex.responsedate,
    c.product AS productwon,
    b.name AS branchename
FROM responses ex
join (SELECT responseset_pk, value_text FROM responses WHERE name = 'Wincode') t
    on t.responseset_pk = ex.responseset_pk
join (SELECT code, product FROM wincode wc WHERE wc.product != '') c
    on c.code =  t.value_text
join branch b on b.pk = ex.branch_pk
WHERE responses.question_pk = 1
```

I don't understand why you need the outer query and/or why you need to select those columns from the subquery if you are ignoring them in the outer query, so I have just left the that off.

Comment: I need the inner query to return all columns at an other place. an other script gets that query, and gets all id's from that query.

a year ago we did such queries with a join, but there were some queries qwhat didn't return everything, so thats why we changed to subqueries for every query we write in these cases... i'll give the joins a new try...

Comment: but besides that, how is it possible that the subquery runs fast, even with the co-related subquery in it, and when you want to select only the pk's of that, it turns into a very slow query?

Comment: i figured it out. When i was working with this query one year ago, i made the joins directly on a table, and then a where on the joined table to get the response. The problem was the left join didn't select the rows where the right had to result. But now i see the difference with you solution, you placed it in a subquery, but joined that one. i think thats the trick. i will try it now, and let you know if that makes everything faster.

Comment: @Bart a further trick to solve the "conditions on a left join" is to move non-key conditions from the WHERE clause to the join's ON clause - the ON clause can have any conditions (many people assume it can only have key-based conditions)